# How to scroll down to hidden section

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, react-hooks, anchor

I have a section that is made out of 2 components:

1. trigger component
2. show/hide component

Basically when I click on trigger component, new component under will appear. This is handled simple by useState

```
const [toShow, setToShow] = useState(0);
```

And then I am using onClick method:

```
onClick={() => setToShow(1)}
```

Showing the element under trigger component:

```
{toShow === 1 && (
            <div className="show-box" id="myHiddenComponent">
                    <HiddenComponent />
            </div>
)}
```

Problem is, I need to access the hidden component with `id="myHiddenComponent"` from my Navbar. That means, the component will be not set to show. But link should understand that it has to set it to be opened and then scroll to the component. Is something like that possible with React ?

Right now I am using Hashlink

```
<HashLink smooth to='#myHiddenComponent'>
  GO TO HIDDEN SECTON
</HashLink>
```

But that does not work unfortunately, since the section is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set state of toShow to 1 onClick on HashLink component

Comment: But how can I do it, since there are two different components in 2 different files ?

Comment: `<HashLink smooth to='#myHiddenComponent' onClick={() => setToShow(1}>
  GO TO HIDDEN SECTON
</HashLink>` should work